# How to input a list of data from console in dart?

Tags: dart, console

In **Dart** I want to take input from user 100 data into a list from console. How can I do that?

```
void main() {
  int value;
  List<int> list = [0];

  var largest = list[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list.add(stdin.readByteSync());
    if (list[i] > largest) {
      largest = list[i];
    }
  }
  print(largest);
}
```

Comment: How is data being sent to your program? 100 lines? How do you want them to be stored? Can you give some examples? Also, what have you tried yourself? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service where you can just ask for some code. But we can help you with your own code.

Comment: Suppose I am taking a fixed list  List<int> list = [0,12,34,44,11,5]; I just want to add the numbers from console input.

Comment: Again, how is this input being sent into Dart? One number per line? Or should it support one line where each number is separated by comma?

Comment: yeah 1 number in line

Comment: Ok, and what have your tried? What is your problem?

Comment: I want to add 100 data in line from console.

Comment: Yes, that part I do understand. But what is your problem with the current code? I can see you are trying to add a `String?` from `stdin.readByteSync()` into a `List` which contains `int`. You will need to parse your `String` to `int` before adding to the `List`.

Comment: Also, if the purpose of the program is to output the largest value, you don't really need to add your numbers to a list.

Comment: In my current code its taking unlimited input I want to fix the length of the list that will take 10 input where i can find the highest value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231520/discussion-between-julemand101-and-tanvir-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some dialog in the chat we ended up with the following solution:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // Create empty list
  final list = <int>[];

  // Number of numbers we want to take
  const numbersWeWant = 100;

  // Loop until we got all numbers
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersWeWant; i++) {
    int? input;

    // This loop is for asking again if we get something we don't see as a number
    do {
      print('Input number nr. $i:');

      // Get a number. input is going to be null if the input is not a number
      input = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? '');
    } while (input == null); // loop as long as we don't got a number

    // Add the number we got to the list
    list.add(input);
  }

  // Use list.reduce to find the biggest number in the list by reducing the
  // list to a single value using the compare method.
  print('Largest number: ${list.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b)}');
}
```